# How can I force visual studio to find a header file when opening a folder

Tags: c++, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, node-addon-api

Visual Studio 2019 does not discover `napi.h`unless I use relative paths while opening a npm project as a folder. The file is located in `node_modules/node-addon-api/napi.h`. How can I force VS to find this header? Is there an `Additional include directory` type option when opening a folder?

The header is automatically discovered on my laptop with the same version of VS2019 and the same environment path. I have `nodejs` tools installed for Visual Studio.

I want to be able to do `#include <napi.h>` and have the header discovered. At the moment I must do `#include "../node_modules/node-addon-api/napi.h"`

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. I think you just need to modify your "Additional include directory" setting for your project. There is also a system wide version of that but unless you want to use this header in every project its best to use the per project version.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for the post. I'm not opening a project, I'm opening a folder and I cannot find such a option when opening a regular folder

Comment: You could use the system wide setting in your IDE compiler settings. I don't have 2019 installed here so I can't point you through the menus to the setting,

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio you can add header paths to third party include folder through a file `CppProperties.json` that you can create and put at the root of your folder or inside the `.vs` folder that gets created.

[Original documentation](https://%20https://learn.mic%20rosoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/open-folder-projects-cpp?view=msvc-170)

### Example of json:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug-test",
      "includePath": [  
        // -----------------------------
        // Example of extra include path:
        "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2022/include"
      ],    
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that this way of doing things is very similar to the "vs code" way with its `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`